# Welcome to my kitchen

Tags: lateral-thinking

Today I mixed some food products and saw interesting outcomes.

> Silverbeet + Gelatin $\equiv$ Snickers
>
> Lime + Nacho $\equiv$ Kiwi
>
> Sesame + Tea $\equiv$ Popcorn

Can you find how these are possible?

Comment: You have some strange recipes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An elementary solution is you are

> going down groups in the [periodic table](https://www.ptable.com/), where the initial letter/s of the foods stand for atomic symbols.

Silverbeet + Gelatin ≡ Snickers

> **Si**licon + **Ge**rmanium = **Sn** (tin)

Lime + Nacho ≡ Kiwi

> **Li**thium + **Na** (sodium) = **K** (potassium)

Sesame + Tea ≡ Popcorn

> **Se**lenium + **Te**llurium = **Po**lonium

Comment: Excellent Tom !!!